# What should I do if my credit card company isn't debiting my bank account even though they're crediting payment?

Tags: credit-card, bank-account

I've been paying my credit card every month at the company's website. They credit me, but never debit my bank account. My bank says the requests are never received from the credit card company *(I called a few times)*. My credit card company says they were paid *(I called them a few times, too)*. What do I do? Just keep paying from my account *(the money is in there, no danger of going into overdraft)*? Is there a time limit, after which it's too late for them to collect? Or, can they come after me, even 20 years from now?

Comment: How many months has this gone on?

Comment: Have you checked with the credit card company that they are debiting the correct bank and account number?

Comment: This is the third billing cycle. To be sure, I re-entered the info this month, and nothing changed.

Comment: @FrankQuarry How did it work out eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as civil remedies, the statute of limitations on debts would apply; you can check what they are for your state. However, it would be difficult for them to pursue this, as they have already declared the debt paid.

There is also the issue of what form your payment is taking (it's probably ACH, but you should check), and how long your bank will honor it; expiration of debts and expiration of ACH are two different matters.

Things you should do:

1. Ask your bank whether they will honor these transfers if they are posted later; get the answer in writing.
2. Notify your credit card company and the bank of the error, and make sure there's a paper trail (e.g. send by email and keep backups of the email).
3. Meticulously document your displayed credit card and bank account balances; take screenshots, keep paper statements, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> (I called a few times).

I would notify both the bank and credit card company *in writing* that your accounts are not being handled correctly. Ask for an explanation and correction.  Set a deadline for them to respond. If registered mail with a delivery receipt is available, use that.

Simply enjoying the fruits of their mistake(s) could be construed as theft or fraud.  Try Googling Susan Madakor, whose account was credited with payments intended for the UN!

You say there is no danger of overdraft.  Could you cover the **total amount** not debited correctly in one lump payment?

The person whose bank account is erroneously funding your credit card must eventually notice something. They will recover funds, through their bank, from the credit card company, who will turn to your card account for payment.

For sure, resist the temptation to take some large cash advances on your credit card!

Comment: When I make a payment from my bank account, I consider that amount debited, so, even if this were to go on for a long time, I would be able to pay it all in one lump sum. If I never use the money, and I've been following up with them, how many times must I use my precious time listening to their call waiting music and getting bounce around &/or disconnected, in order to fix THEIR mistake? I called because I want to do the honest thing, but, at the same time, I don't work for my credit card company.

Comment: It's emphasized in the answer, do not call, notify both parties in writing instead. That way you can prove that you tried to fix the situation.